# npm не видит команду webpack

Tags: npm, webpack

установил webpack через npm (и глобально и локально). ниже на картинке список модулей в папке. при попытке запустить webpack npm говорит, что такой команды нет. почему? кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким глюком npm?[image: текущий списоко модулей в папке такой]

Answer (score 1):

Глобальная установка позволяет установить пакет как приложение, которое можно запустить по его имени (например тот же npm). Важно учесть, что ссылка на приложение обновляется только в новой сессии в терминале.

Локальная установка, устанавливает пакет в ближайшую наверх папку с проектом.

Локальные пакеты не загружаются как приложения, а копируются в папку node_modules/<название пакета>/

Чтобы их запустить надо запустить команду npm run <название пакета>. Так npm попытается запустить пакет как приложение из ближайшей папки node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

Запустите команду `hash -r` и проверьте опять.

Comment: rehash тоже не может обнаружить - bash: rehash: command not found ;(

Comment: я обновил ответ

Comment: да, hash -r отработал, но результат осталься таким же: bash: webpack: command not found

Comment: решил проблему установив webpack глобально.. наверно какой-то баг в локальной установке

Comment: у вас в вопросе написано, что вы устанавливали глобально. локально работать не будет без настройки PATH.

Comment: Все верно, без задание дополнительного пути в переменное окружения PATH, вызов webpack работать не будет.